# Connect local domain to Django

Tags: django, dns, localhost, appdomain

I have several applications that I'm running on Docker. Each one of them has own domain, however when I start containers I can access them only on `127.0.0.1:8000` or `127.0.0.1:8001`. But I need to reach them on domain like `test1.mydomain.local` and `test2.mydomain.local`.

I tried to change my host file like this:

> 127.0.0.1 *.mydomain.local
>
> 127.0.0.1 localhost

However when I start docker again - it doesn't work. I have `.env` file where all domains are written down but I don't get how to get this worked.

Please help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to specify wildcards in the host file. Set them explicitly or use a local DNS.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to do that? Can't find how to make it in a right way....

Comment: Add `127.0.0.1 test1.mydomain.local` to your host file. And if this app is accessible via port 8000, then access it with test1.mydomain.local:8000